# Cookie lost after another post submit

Tags: php, post, cookies

I have filters using `$_POST` and trying to store them into cookies.

It saves and remembers, but after another `$_POST` submit cookie is lost.

And yes I have in `header.php` file `session_start()` function.

Code:

```
setcookie('pP', $_POST['perPage'], time()+3600);

if(isset($_COOKIE["pP"]) && $_COOKIE["pP"]==25) {
    $per_page=25;
} elseif(isset($_COOKIE["pP"]) && $_COOKIE["pP"]==50) {
    $per_page=50;
} elseif(!isset($_COOKIE["pP"])) {
    $per_page=25;
}
```

I've tried using `$_SESSION` variables too, but still nothing.

Code:

```
$_SESSION['pP']=$_POST['pocetZaznamu'];

if(isset($_SESSION['pP']) && $_SESSION['pP']==25) {
    $per_page=25;
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['pP']) && $_SESSION['pP']==50) {
    $per_page=50;
} elseif(!isset($_SESSION['pP'])) {
    $per_page=25;
}
```

How can I fix this problem? I want use `$_POST` not `$_GET` and remember `$_POST` values.

Comment: Don't store such data in cookies, use session variables instead!

Comment: I've tried session variables too, but result is the same, variable is lost after another $_POST submit.

Comment: Then your session is obviously _not_ restored, you have a problem somewhere. I suggest you post your session handling code here.

Comment: $_SESSION['pP']=$_POST['perPage'];

if(isset($_SESSION['pP']) && $_SESSION['pP']==25) {
 $per_page=25;
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['pP']) && $_SESSION['pP']==50) {
 $per_page=50;
} elseif(!isset($_SESSION['pP'])) {
 $per_page=25;
}

Comment: Sorry, this is impossible to read. Please use the `edit` button below the question to add information to your question.